# ASP.NET Core MVC - add to cart implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, e-commerce

I'm learning ASP.NET Core MVC, and trying to make some simple food ordering web app.

Those are my models:

```
public class Cart
{
    [Key]
    public int CartId { get; set; }
    
    public List<CartItem> Items{ get; set; } 
}

public class CartItem
{
    [Key]
    public int CartItemId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Food FoodItem { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Food
{
    [Key]
    public int FoodId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FoodName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float Price { get; set; }
}
```

In this view, I display all food available, and simple "Add to cart" button:

```
@model IEnumerable<Food>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index Food</h1>
<form method="post">
<table class="table" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Food Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th></th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var obj in Model){

            <tr>
                <td width="10%">@obj.FoodId</td>
                <td width="30%">@obj.FoodName</td>
                <td width="30%">@obj.Description</td>
                <td width="30%">@obj.Price</td>
                <td><button asp-controller="Cart" asp-action="AddToCart(@obj)">Add</button></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

This is the cart controller:

```
public class CartController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public CartController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //POST
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddToCart(Cart item)
    {
        _db.Cart.Add(item);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

The problem is that I couldn't figure out the way to pass the data from that view's foreach loop to my controller.

I tried putting `<label>` tags inside `<td>` elements for every property so I can use `asp-for` tag helpers, but that gave me an error.

I would appreciate your advice.

Thank you in advance!

Tommy.

Answer (score 0):

```
May be you need add each element inside the form

@model IEnumerable<Food>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index Food</h1>

<table class="table" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Food Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th></th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var obj in Model){
         <form method="post">
            <tr>
                <td width="10%"><input asp-for="FoodId" value="@obj.FoodId" readonly /> </td>
                <td width="30%"><input asp-for="FoodName" value="@obj.FoodName" readonly /></td>
                @*Continue with other fields*@
                <td><button asp-controller="Cart" asp-action="AddToCart" type="submit">Add</button></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `<form>` inside foreach loop,add  hidden input ,you could check the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) related with sending form data

```
<table class="table" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Food Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var obj in Model)
        {
            <form  asp-action="AddToCart"  method="post">
            <tr>
                <td width="10%">
                   
                    <label asp-for=" @obj.FoodId">@obj.FoodId</label>
                    <input type="text" asp-for="@obj.FoodId" hidden/>
                </td>
                <td width="30%">                    
                    <label asp-for="@obj.FoodName">@obj.FoodName</label>
                    <input type="text" asp-for="@obj.FoodName" hidden/>
                </td>
                <td width="30%">                    
                    <label asp-for="@obj.Description">@obj.Description</label>
                    <input type="text" asp-for="@obj.Description" hidden/>
                </td>
                <td width="30%">
                    <label asp-for="@obj.Price">@obj.Price</label>
                    <input type="text" asp-for="@obj.Price" hidden/>
                </td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Add" /></td>
            </tr>
            </form>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and you could Press F12 to check the name attribute of input tag,in your case it would be like `obj.FoodId`.....

and the value pass to your controller should be type of `Food` instead of `Cart`,the parameter should be obj for modelbinding(You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#complex-types-1) ralted)

It works on my side now:
[image]

Add you could check the documents related with [Reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) and [Saving](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data) Related Data with EFCore